# Flutter Firebase no error when using where and orderBy query, but flashes data and disappears

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

**SOLVED (In case someone with the same problem tries to find answers check the comments)**

So I am trying to display data from my database using a where query to check if the array contains a certain user and then order it by the time it was sent or updated. Usually what I heard is that there should be an error, and in some cases an error with a link to add a composite index to the database, but I am not receiving neither of them. The data actually displays just as i want it to, but literally flashes the data for a second and disappears. Does someone know the reason for it? And is there a solution to it? Thank you!!

Here is the code that I have to retrieve the data from the firebase database:

```
Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> getChats(String user) async {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("ChatRoom")
        .where("users", arrayContains: user)
        .orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

Here is the code to display the data

```
Stream messageStream;

void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getMyUserID().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        fetchChats(value);
      });
    });
  }

//Gets my User ID
  _getMyUserID() async {
    final myUserId = await getUser();
    var myUserVar = myUserId;
    return myUserVar;
  }

fetchChats(String myUserId) async {
    // print(myUserId);
    _showProgress(widget.title);
    messageStream = await DatabaseMethods().getChats(myUserId);
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

// Widget to display the List of the Chats
  Widget displayMessages() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: messageStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return snapshot.hasData
            ? ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                  return chatList(
                    ds["userName"],
                  );
                },
              )
            : Container();
      },
    );
  }

chatList(String usersName) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
    width: size.width;
    height: 80;
    child: Text(usersName);
    ):
}
```

Comment: Post the code where you are rendering the data on screen.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad I have updated the question with the code to display it

Comment: What it is happening is that the snapshot.data is returning null, but no error is showing so it is straight up displaying `Container();`

Comment: Nvm I got it lol. In case someone comes inside here to check what was the problem. It is simple lol, I was running the app using an ios simulator, and apparently the exception message with the link does not show, I ended up trying it with an android emulator and got the exception with the link to get a composite index.